# Google analytics code registering 3 hits for each page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have added the following GA script on each page of my website:

```
<script async src=<?PHP print ('"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id='.$gaid.'"'); ?>></script>
<script>
var gaid = <?PHP print('"'.$gaid.'"'); ?>;
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', gaid);
gtag('config', gaid, {'custom_map': {'dimension2': 'Za'} });
gtag('event', 'set_za', {'Za': <?php print("'".za()."'"); ?>} );
gtag('config', gaid, {'custom_map': {'dimension3': 'Zd'} });
gtag('event', 'set_zd', {'Zd': <?php print("'".zd()."'"); ?>} );
</script>
```

So although I’m seeing my hits in Google analytics, each hit is showing up 3 times! Why is this running 3 times for each site page? I suspect it has something to do with adding the 2 custom dimensions – but I think I’ve done this per GA examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pageview hit is sent each time you're calling `gtag('config' ...)`. You'll have to rearrange your code to have all the custom mappings to be defined in a single call, like:

```
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', gaid, {'custom_map': {'dimension2': 'Za', 'dimension3': 'Zd'} });
gtag('event', 'set_za', {'Za': <?php print("'".za()."'"); ?>} );
gtag('event', 'set_zd', {'Zd': <?php print("'".zd()."'"); ?>} );
```